# Using Gauss' theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, gauss-law, dirac-delta-distributions

I am working through some questions and I am stuck on the working of this one:

[image]

Where the working to the answer is here:

[image]

Can someone explain the highlighted section as I can't see where it comes from?

Comment: The area of a sphere is $4\pi r^2$.

Comment: @Drjh where does the $\frac{1}{R^2}$ factor come from?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/488220/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic interesting. However, I am having trouble understanding the more explicit working to the solution as I cant see how the transition was made from the surface integral to the $4\pi R^2 \cdot \frac{1}{R^2}$

Comment: The site standard for math expressions is [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which is very similar to LaTex.  We *strongly* discourage posting images of text or equations as they are not searchable by the site engine and in the case of photos of written script often hard to read.

Comment: *where does the $1/R^2$  factor come from?* From the inverse-square  field $\vec r/r^3$ on the surface.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the more explicit working I found for this question which is what I was interested in:
[image]