# Gauss law for magnetism on electromagnetic wave

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

[image]

While studying electromagnetic waves, I'm confused with Gauss law for magnetism.

Shouldn't magnetic flux be zero in shown surface? Or do I understand it wrong?

**Edited image after Mauricio's answer**
[image]

Comment: Thanks @user10001111 for grammar corrections

Comment: No problem! Sorry, but I cannot answer the question since I am not specialized in magnetism. I will try to take a look at it! ;)

Comment: @kavin : $B$ has zero divergence (Maxwell equation). This does not mean that $B$ iself must be zero. See also [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/488220/divergence-of-frac-hat-bf-rr2-equiv-frac-bf-rr3-what-is-th).

Comment: @Kurt G. Hmm... That makes sense. But every megnatic field line forms a closed loop.In these case i'm confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines on your picture are *not* magnetic field lines. They are lines (with arrows) to represent the direction and strength of the magnetic field at each point along the z-axis at a fixed time.

The wave in your picture has a form something like
$$ {\bf B} = B_0 \sin (kz - \omega t) \hat{\bf j}\ ,$$
where $\hat{\bf j}$ is a unit vector along the y-axis.

The divergence of this field
$$ \nabla \cdot {\bf B} = \frac{\partial B_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial B_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial z} = 0\ .$$
Then, by Gauss's *theorem*, we know that
$$\oint \nabla \cdot {\bf B}\ dV = \oint {\bf B}\cdot d{\bf A} = 0\ $$
and thus "Gauss's law for magnetism" (a.k.a. the solenoidal law or no monopole law) is satisfied.

This is true for *any* surface including the ones you have attempted to draw.

Comment: I don't know why gauss law for magnatic field is known as solenoidal law.Can you please explain?

Comment: I haven't heard that expression. However a purely solenoidal field is one with zero divergence but has curl. Gauss law for B field says there is zero divergence. Is probably why its called that

Comment: https://courses.ansys.com/index.php/courses/magnetostatics-in-free-space/lessons/the-solenoidal-law-lesson-5/ @kavin

Comment: That makes sense.Thanks @ProfRob

Comment: Thanks @jensenpaull

Answer (score 3):

Gauss' law for magnetism says that there must be zero net flux about a closed surface, the picture seems to indicate the flux through an open surface.

Comment: Oh.. but what if i assume a sphere there?Wouldn't megnatic flux be coming out of sphere?

Comment: @kavin For a closed surface the net flux will be zero.

Comment: It would be nice if you can share an image explaining that.

Comment: @kavin I do not have time for it. The mind picture is the following: there are just as many arrows coming as those coming out.

Comment: Okay No problem @Mauricio.But my understanding  is magnatic flux at any point where em wave affects would only be coming outwards.Then flux would be non zero. There's where i'm confused.

Comment: Sure but the wave is everywhere, there are vectors at the bottom and at the top of the sphere pointing in the same direction (let's say upwards). Flux In+ flux out=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134241/discussion-between-kavin-and-mauricio).

Comment: The lines on the picture don't represent flux at all.