Divergence of Electric Field of Point Charge is always zero
I might have a bug in my brain, but I just can't figure this out. Please help. According to the first of the Maxwell Equations, we have
$$
\nabla\cdot\vec{E}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}.
$$
And we have for the electric field of a point charge
$$
\vec{E} = k\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3},
$$
where $k=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$, $\vec{r}=[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ and $r=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$. Now I want to find the divergence of this electric field $\vec{E}$, so let's derive the i-th component w.r.t. $x_i$:
$$
\frac{d}{dx_i}\vec{E}_i = k\frac{r^3 - 3r^2r'x_i}{r^6} = k\frac{1}{r^3}-3k\frac{rx_i^2}{r^6} = k\frac{1}{r^3}-3k\frac{x_i^2}{r^5}
$$
where I used $r'=\frac{dr}{dx}=\frac{x}{r}$.
Now let's add up the tree derivatives.
$$
\nabla\cdot\vec{E}=\sum_{i=1}^{3} \frac{d}{dx_i}\vec{E}_i = \frac{3k}{r^3} - 3k\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}{r^5} = \frac{3k}{r^3} - \frac{3k}{r^3} = 0.
$$
So the divergence of the electric field of a point charge would always be zero, when it actually should be equal to $\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$. Please help me figuring out, what I am doing wrong or where I have a misconception. I'm thankful for every kind help :)

I think you’re computing divergence and not gradient.

@GrapefruitIsAwesome You are completely right, I confused the to terms. Sorry for the trouble. My problem still persists, unfortunately.

Similar, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/488220/23615. This question has a few minor variations that have been asked before.

Does this answer your question? Divergence of $\frac{ \hat {\bf r}}{r^2} \equiv \frac{{\bf r}}{r^3}$, what is the 'paradox'?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/816311

Because this a point charge, the charge is 0 everywhere except the origin. This is consistent (everywhere except the origin) with your calculation that found the divergence to be 0.
What you didn't consider is that your expression for the field,
$$\vec{E}=k\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}$$
is not defined at the origin, and therefore you can't use it to find the divergence at the origin.

Oh now I get it! I misinterpreted the first Maxwell equation and assumed that it implied a constant divergence across the room. Thank you, your answer helped me finding my mistake :)

You missed one point while calculation.
Let me make calculation more easier by going towards spherical polar coordinates.
Since $\vec E$ = $E_r \hat r + E_\theta \hat \theta + E_\phi \hat \phi$ = $\frac{k}{r^2}\hat r$
For spherical polar coordinates
$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec E =  \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2 E_r)+0+0=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2 \frac{k}{r^2})=0$
(only if $r\neq 0$ because $\frac{1}{r^2}$ is not defined at r=0. So at r= 0 divergence of Electric field is infinite and elsewhere it is zero, which can explain the result $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec{E}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$.

Hey Chauhan, I'm sorry but I don't get where $\nabla\cdot E = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2 E_r)$ comes from. Shouldn't it actually be $\nabla\cdot E = \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(E_r)$?
Because afaik the first component of the gradient in polar coordinates should be $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$

Hii tobi-v, here I used divergence of vector in spherical polar coordinates which makes calculation easy. If you want to know how divergence of vector field define in spherical polar coordinates see this Wikipedia link " https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates ". Keep asking.

Okay it seems I'm missing some basic concepts here. $\nabla$ seems to be different when determining gradient vs divergence and I surmise this has to do with the distinction between source and destination coordinates? That's a new concept for me - can you recommend a good introduction to the topic, as well as to the derivation of the divergence in spherical coordinates?
